# How to implement navigation using React and NGINX?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, amazon-ec2, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a website in React.js, deployed on an AWS EC2 instance.

To deploy it, I use Bitbucket pipelines system.

As a server, I use NGINX.

My question is: To use the navigation between the screens, should I set something on NGINX config file? Because if I try to use "link to", for example to go to home page, my url becomes
 `http://IP.compute-1.amazonaws.com/register` but it results to be a 404 not found

Edit:  Router:

```
<BrowserRouter> 
            <Switch>
             <Route path="/home" component={Home} exact/>
             <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
             <Route path="/" component={Login}/>
             <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
            <Route component={Error}/>

           </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
```

navigation:

```
<Link to="/register">
            <button className="loginRegisterButton">
              Create a New Account
            </button>
            </Link>
```

path that gives "404 not found nginx":

`http://ec2-***-**-**-**.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home`

Plus, I think that on NGINX I don't have all the files that I need:
in home/ec2-user:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDUyk.png)

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to configure anything additionally for nginx, other than ensuring our domain is configured properly. You can use the react-router and react-router-dom packages from npm to easily route between multiple pages.

Comment: it's still adding /home at the end of the url and so not working. I followed this tutorial https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/6517/react-router-tutorial

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your react router code? Please include the misbehaving path as well.